# Regex to allow head and trail whitespace in the String content

Tags: java, regex

I've this regex with me `\\s.*\\s|\\s` which is not allowing me to have a white space (optional, any number of whitespaces) in the beginning or/and end of the String.

```
String regex = "\\s.*\\s|\\s";
System.out.println("Hello World".matches(regex)); -> FALSE
System.out.println(" Hello World ".matches(regex)); -> TRUE
System.out.println(" Hello World".matches(regex)); -> FALSE
System.out.println("Hello World ".matches(regex)); -> FALSE
```

Please help, tell me where I'm going wrong in my regex

Comment: Could you please clarify what is wrong with your regex? The code above shows appropriate values per the given regex. What would you expect? Maybe, the last `\s` should be quantified to match `"    "`, then try `"\\s.*\\s|\\s*"`

Comment: Maybe [`"(?s)\\s.*|.*\\s|\\s*"`](http://ideone.com/J1vtGv) is what you seek?

Comment: Any feedback? Is my last suggestion what you need?

Comment: I wanted pattern like this "\\s*.+\\s*" and I got it. Thank you

Comment: `"\\s*.+\\s*"` is most probably not what you need. If you need to match ANY string that has at least 1 char, use `(?s).+`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following pattern worked for me:

```
@Test
public void testRegex() {
    final String regex = "\\s*.+\\s*";
    assertTrue(Pattern.matches(regex, "Hello World"));
    assertTrue(Pattern.matches(regex, " Hello World"));
    assertTrue(Pattern.matches(regex, " Hello World "));
    assertTrue(Pattern.matches(regex, "Hello World "));
    assertTrue(Pattern.matches(regex, "  "));
}
```

The * character matches 0 or more of the value preceding it, in this case, the whitespace (\s). So \s* at the front and end of the regex allows you your optional whitespace at the beginning or end. The . matches any character and the + means one or more, so the .+ allows a middle between your spaces.

As you'll notice, with my regex "  " is a perfectly acceptable match. To get a better match to your needs, I think we need to know more of your requirements.

Comment: With your `\\s*.+\\s*` (equal to `.+`) regex, any string with no linebreaks and one or more characters will match.

Comment: I agree with you Wiktor, but my request variable holding this regex won't have any line break.